# What is acceptable length of time for flagging incomplete questions.

Tags: discussion, moderators

I've searched for an answer on this subject and point me in the direction if anyone knows for certain. I've tagged this moderators and well the question is about flagging and hopefully john or pete or any other moderator will be able to answer.

I've come across a lot of unanswered questions since well there is many as your aware and it would be nice if the site had as few unanswered questions as possible, but a lot of these questions are unanswered for a reason and a large amount of these questions are because the questioner has failed to provide enough details for people to even answer.

How long do you give questions despite people asking to provide more details before they should be flagged?

Answer (score 1):

There is no set time. But if they're not back after a week I think it's safe to say the issue isn't a pressing matter and the question can be closed. They can always edit it and flag it to be reopened.

Comment: Thanks John for the information, I'll flag the ones that I can't answer due to lack of information and then let the moderators make the final decision.